# Find min value based on Some conditions in python list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list value. I want to find a min value of Rank based on the same category values.

```
[{'PlayerName': 'aaaa', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 1}, {'PlayerName': ' bbbb', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 18}, {'PlayerName': ' cccc', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 2}, {'PlayerName': ' ddddd', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 33}]
```

above the list, value to get the output like this

```
[{'PlayerName': 'aaaa', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 1},{'PlayerName': ' cccc', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 2}]
```

Thank you so much for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `dict.setdefault` to groupby `Category` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = [{'PlayerName': 'aaaa', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 1}, {'PlayerName': ' bbbb', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 18}, {'PlayerName': ' cccc', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 2}, {'PlayerName': ' ddddd', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 33}]
r = {}
for i in data:
    r.setdefault(i['Category'], []).append(i)
print([min(v, key=lambda x: x['Rank']) for _, v in r.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'PlayerName': 'aaaa', 'Category': 'MVP', 'Rank': 1}, {'PlayerName': ' cccc', 'Category': 'LVP', 'Rank': 2}]
```